# Do I need a specific order for Shellcode?What am I doing wrong when turning this into shellcode?

Tags: assembly, shellcode

I started Assembly today in order to create shell-code.The ASM was fine and after a while I created this:

```
[SECTION .text]

global _start


_start:

        call ender

        starter:
        mov al, 4
        mov bl, 1
        pop ecx
        mov dl, 21
        int 0x80

        xor eax, eax
        mov al, 1
        xor ebx,ebx
        int 0x80

        ender:
        call starter
        db 10,'Shellcode forever!',10 ,10
```

Which worked well:

```
Shellcode forever!

root@root:~/Desktop# clear;nasm -f elf test.asm;ld -s -o test test.o;./test
```

So I then used 'objdump -d test' and got this:

```
test:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048060 <.text>:
 8048060:   e8 11 00 00 00          call   0x8048076
 8048065:   b0 04                   mov    $0x4,%al
 8048067:   b3 01                   mov    $0x1,%bl
 8048069:   59                      pop    %ecx
 804806a:   b2 15                   mov    $0x15,%dl
 804806c:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 804806e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8048070:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
 8048072:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
 8048074:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
 8048076:   e8 ea ff ff ff          call   0x8048065
 804807b:   0a 53 68                or     0x68(%ebx),%dl
 804807e:   65                      gs
 804807f:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
 8048080:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
 8048081:   63 6f 64                arpl   %bp,0x64(%edi)
 8048084:   65 20 66 6f             and    %ah,%gs:0x6f(%esi)
 8048088:   72 65                   jb     0x80480ef
 804808a:   76 65                   jbe    0x80480f1
 804808c:   72 21                   jb     0x80480af
 804808e:   0a 0a                   or     (%edx),%cl
```

but when I turned it into shellcode :

```
char code[] = "\xe8\x11\x00\x00\x00\xb0\x04\xb3\x01\x59\xb2\x15\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80\xe8\xea\xff\xff\xff\x0a\x53\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x20\x66\x6f\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x21\x0a\x0a";
```

It didnt work.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you turn it into a shellcode ? Are there any endinanness issues you're not taking care of ?

Comment: Maybe trying with nasm2shell, as2shell or bin2shell which are converting NASM, GNU as and binary files directly to shellcode might be worth it. http://blog.markloiseau.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/bin2shell.tar.gz

Comment: Didnt work and the shellcode was far too long...

Comment: It didnt work, Im running 32 but maybe that's why?

Comment: It might not be that, but it is worth saying that the use of zeroes in \xe8\x11\x00\x00\x00 might be considered as the end of the string you're declaring.

Comment: Try running it in gdb to see exactly what's happening. Does it print an error message?

Comment: Make sure you only convert the actual code and not the ELF headers and stuff. Also replace the initial `CALL` with a short `JMP` to get rid of 0 bytes.

Comment: The conversion seems right. Perhaps what's not working is the way you're trying to run the shellcode. What are you doing exactly to test it?

Comment: [Pointer to string in stand-alone binary code without .data section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57295376) shows how to use `objcopy` and `hexdump` to turn the `.text` section of a `.o` into a C string reliably, without having to parse `objdump` output.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
nasm -f elf test.asm
```

ELF is a binary format, which is fine for producing an executable and is the reason your standalone test works, but shellcode comes in raw format rather than having nice things such as headers, sections and the like.

To get said raw bytes, all you need to do is replace `elf` with `bin`:

```
nasm -f bin test.asm
```

This will produce a raw object using the mnemonics you have specified. To make life easier for myself, I generally include:

```
[bits 32]
```

or

```
[bits 64]
```

in the assembler file to get the right architecture.

Changing to direct binary output *will* break your linking-an-executable test, as the linker links ELF-compatible objects, not raw lumps of binary. There is no workaround for this - but there is no reason you cannot produce both this compiled version and the binary version.

On Linux systems, I generally don't bother linking directly and instead use a small test rig that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096U

uint8_t buffer[] = { 
    0xeb, 0x01, 0x90, ...
};

typedef int (* func)();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    func f;
    mprotect((void*)((size_t)&buffer[0] & ~(PAGE_SIZE -1)), 
             2*PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC);
    f = (func) &buffer[0];
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

which I sometimes modify for different cases e.g. I introduce the relevant copy environment. To start using it, compile with:

```
gcc -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -std=gnu99 -o testshell testshell.c
```

this runs `execstack` to enable an executable stack in your binary, which is not a realistic target environment but hey this *is* a test, and turns off the stack protector, which again would be present on targets but gets in the way for basic development.