# How to convert an assembler program to shellcode correctly?

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, shellcode

I programmed a program in nasm (x64) which should execute `/bin/bash`, and that works fine. Then i ran the program with `objdump -D` and i wrote down the machine code like this: `\xbb\x68\x53\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x62\x61\x73\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05`. Then i ran this with `./shell $(python -c 'print "\xbb\x68\x53\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x62\x61\x73\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"')` and i got an illegal instruction. But the assembler program worked fine! Can someone help?

shell.c:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)()) argv[1];
    (int)(*func)();
}
```

bash.asm:

```
section .text
global start
start:
    mov rbx, 0x68
    push rbx
    mov rbx, 0x7361622f6e69622f
    push rbx
    mov rdi, rsp
    push rax
    push rdi
    mov rsi, rsp
    mov al, 59
    syscall
```

objdump:

```
./bash:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <start>:
  401000:   bb 68 00 00 00          mov    $0x68,%ebx
  401005:   53                      push   %rbx
  401006:   48 bb 2f 62 69 6e 2f    movabs $0x7361622f6e69622f,%rbx
  40100d:   62 61 73 
  401010:   53                      push   %rbx
  401011:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  401014:   50                      push   %rax
  401015:   57                      push   %rdi
  401016:   48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  401019:   b0 3b                   mov    $0x3b,%al
  40101b:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Comment: You left out the 3 zero bytes of the first instruction. shellcode like this should not have zero bytes but that doesn't mean you can simply leave them out. You need to write code that doesn't have them. You can just do `push $0x68` instead of the first two instructions. PS: you used `rax` without initializing it that's unlikely to work reliably.

Comment: @Jester thank you for the tip. But when i run the shellcode with strace i got this. ```execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash"], 0x7ffcdcd335eastrace: umoven: short read (6 < 8) @0x7ffcdcd33ffa
 /* 322 vars, unterminated */) = -1 EFAULT (Ungültige Adresse)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++```

Comment: You may wish to look at this answer which eliminates the NUL (0) bytes by using different instructions and executes `/bin/sh` (you can amend it to use `/bin/bash` :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57295376/3857942 . It also presents a mechanism to generate the shellcode string automatically rather than copying info from objdump by hand.

Comment: Your code doesn't zero out RDX (which is the last parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are omitting the zero bytes here:

```
\xbb\x68\x53\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x62\x61\x73\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05
```

as opposed to

```
  401000:   bb 68 00 00 00          mov    $0x68,%ebx
```

The zero bytes are part of the instructions and cannot be skipped. So you have to include them.

The problem is, however, that the zero bytes would terminate the argument string and hence have to be avoided. It is your duty as shellcode designer to construct it in a way, that it does not include byte values that may not occur. In many cases this means no zero bytes, because the shellcode is injected as a C string, but other values may be problematic in other situations, too.